# Is there any delegate method to know the user gives rating my app or not yet?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am using below code to rate the aap by user.. but I am confused that how I know the user rate my app this time. I want to show alert view up for rate, but the user did not rate yet then I want to show that alertview again:

```
isRate = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
rate = [isRate integerForKey:@"rating"];
[isRate setInteger:rate+1 forKey:@"rating"];
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa";
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?", str];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@type=Purple+Software&id=", str];
str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@id869231055", str];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I recommend using [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater) for showing an alert view to ask the user to rate your app. It is very small and easy to use, and keeps track of whether the user has clicked on the button to rate the app or if they want to be reminded later or if they don't want to be reminded again. You can easily set after how many days and how many uses or how many significant events should the rating alert show up.